# Ubuntu 13.04 format my NTFS partition

Tags: installation, ntfs, format, data-recovery, partitioning

I install Ubuntu 13.04, choosing the option "Replace Win7".

When my computer reboots, i see that my other data pratition is missing.

my Win7 partition was 100gb, and the other 220gb was the data.

I have a lot of importatnt data, how can i get them back?

I don't use my computer since the fresh install. I don't want to lose all of my data in the hard drive.

Please help me.

Thx for yuour replies.

Comment: Well, when you choose "Replace Windows 7" you are telling the installer to format the disk which contains Windows 7. If that is really what happened, I am sorry to tell you that your data has been mostly erased.

Comment: For future reference, you should probably choose the advanced option where you get to choose your own partitioning scheme..

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't touch the partition, or restarted your system, there **might** be a possibility to get most/some of the data back.  You can try using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

TestDisk is powerful free data recovery software!

**Make sure that you read about TestDisk to know how to use it before you attempt to recover anything.**

Of course **there is no guarantee** that Testdisk will recover any of your data, but I think it worth a try.